# How to Prepend and Append in JavaScript textarea dynamically without submit button

Tags: javascript, angular

app.component.html

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" cols="40" [(ngModel)]="answer" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)">
</textarea>

<br><br>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" cols="40">
{{formated}}
</textarea>
```

app.component.ts

```
answer = '';
formated: string

onKeyUp(event: any) {
this.formated = event.target.value.replace(/\/^/g, "hi");
this.formated = event.target.value.replace(/\n/g, "welcome to xyz");
}
```

User inputs multiple names with a line break to differentiate

```
name one
name two
name three
```

prepend and append as

```
Hi name one welcome to xyz
Hi name two welcome to xyz
hi name three welcome to xyz
```

Appending is working fine but prepend is not working as expected and it's completely ignoring the first line

Comment: You prepend 'hi' to the `event.target.value` and assign it to a variable. Then you append 'welcome..' againt to `event.target.value`. In both cases the event value is not changed. It is always 'stack'. Therefore you overwrite your prepended string with your appending another string.

Comment: this works for only one event, how can I extend it to all names (all separate lines) of the text area

Comment: reframe your question as you've not mentioned this use case above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
const input = event.target.value;

// convert input to an array of non empty names
const names = input.split('\n').filter(val => val !== '');

// format the names
this.formatted = names.map(name => `Hi ${name} welcome to xyz`).join('\n');
```

#### Working Example

```js
const handleKeyUp = () => {
    const input = document.querySelector('.input').value;

    // convert input to an array of non empty names
    const names = input.split('\n').filter(val => val !== '');

    // format the names
    const formattedNames = names.map(name => `Hi ${name} welcome to xyz`).join('\n');

    // display the formatted names
    const output = document.querySelector('.ouput');
    output.value = formattedNames;
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea class="input" rows="10" cols="40" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()">
  </textarea>

  <textarea class="ouput" rows="10" cols="40">
  </textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, this applies to only one name (one event), how can I apply this to all names, which can be differentiated by a line break

Comment: At first, you need to edit your question as you've nowhere mentioned what exactly is the use case. Questions only conveys to prepend & append problem. Second, where do you need these names to be displayed in your HTML file? Third, you can intercept only one event at a time. So, you'll need to save names in an array and iterate it as follows `const formattedNames = nameArr.map(name => name).join('\n')`

Comment: Edited the question, I have two textareas, first one takes input, second one gives output. As user types name + enter key + name + enter key and so on, it should show the result in textarea with the prepend and append. Quick question is it possible to do this dynamically